# How output directive using ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have some items in a list that contain other directives, I would like to output the directive and have it render.  `*ngFor` is rendering the value correctly to the browser but is not rendering the directive.  Is this possible?  If I add the directive directly to this template it renders so I know the page is aware of the directive.

```
<ul id="sidebar-wrapper" class="clearfix nav navbar-default sidebar-nav clearfix">
               <li *ngFor="#nav of navigationItems">
                     <span [innerHTML]="nav.directive"></span>
               </li>
               <ul>
```

Comment: You need to show more code.  In particular, do you have `directives: [MyDirectiveComponent]` (or whatever the class name is) specified in the component that is using the template you show above?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this is the way you should reference a component with in a component, I assume you are trying to display a list of components.

```
<ul id="sidebar-wrapper" class="clearfix nav navbar-default sidebar-nav clearfix">
  <li *ngFor="#nav of navigationItems">
     <mydirective [nav]="nav"></mydirective>
  </li>
<ul>
```

An Example Template that shows a list of posts would look like,

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="#post of posts">
   <post-card [post]="post"></post-card>
</div>
```

Here the posts-card is a component that we used to show how a post show look like in a card format. The list would iterate through the posts array and then for each post, render a post-card element passing the post element along to the post-card element to give it the information it needs to render itself.

Comment: that just causes an exception to be thrown

Comment: what does your nav.directives contain ? does your nav object have directives property ? Can you add more details of your components, it will really help me get to an answer quicker.

Comment: a plain and empty directive like <mydirective></mydirective>.  If I put the directive in the above template somewhere it will render properly.  When I view the markup in the browser I can see the directive there it just didn't render.

Comment: got it, what you mean by directive is component, you want to show a list of components.

Comment: @HonorableChow i updated the answer, let me know if I got your question properly.